# AWS SDK NoClassDefFoundError in jar used as an extension of smartfox

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm exporting a project to a jar that is used as a server extension in SmartFox, my project uses Amazon AWS SDK to upload some files to the cloud. The problem is that when I run the SmartFox it throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-22" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials at...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

The AWSCredentials class is in the classpath, when I downloaded the SDK files I notice that there was a "third-party" folder with jars that the AWS may need, I wasn't sure if I had to add them to the classpath, so I did it, but nothing changed.. also my project is a regular java project, not a web project, could that be the problem? If that's the case I'm screwed cause I'm not allowed to change the project type.. Thanks for any help in advance...

Comment: Can you give more details about your development environment? How are you building the project into a jar? Are you including the AWS core jar when building? My first guess is that the AWS SDK is not being built into the new jar you are making. I don't know anything about SmartFox but it sounds like you could either build the jar into your new jar, or just use SmartFox with the AWS jar as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty easy, SmartFox has a `/SmartFoxServer_2X/SFS2X/extensions/__ lib __` directory where you are supposed to put all the jars that your extension jar may need.

I pasted all the "third-party" jars and the SDK jar itself inside this directory and it almost worked. The problem that I faced after that was an incompatibility between two jars from the same library (http-client from apache), one residing at `__ lib __` and the other residing at `/SmartFoxServer_2X/SFS2X/lib` that contains all the jars that SmartFox uses.

I think the problem was that the SmartFox classloader was loading the http-client `.class` files from the jar located at `/SmartFoxServer_2X/SFS2X/lib` whose version was a bit older than the one I pasted from the Amazon third party libraries and didn't have a couple of methods that AWS needed. Anyway, I updated SmartFox to the lastest version and that did the trick. Of course I also could have pasted the jar from the `__ lib __` folder to `lib` to have the same version.